# submitHandler fires for invalid form - jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that creates it's input fields dynamically. It was working great but now I need to call a function when the form is valid. My problem is that as soon the form is loaded the `submitHandler` triggers. I verified it by adding `alert("alert")` inside the submit handler.

```
 <input type="text" id="FName" name="FName" class = "vali" />   //these input fields are for demonstration; these are created dynmaiclly
 <input type="text" id="SName" name="SName" class = "vali"/>

 <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit">   //have tried type="submit" as well 
 </button>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.vali').each(function () {
            $(this).rules('add', {
                required: true,
                messages: { required: "Can't be empty" },

                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    alert("alert"); // this fires as soon as the page load. 
                }
            })
        });
 });

 </script>
```

Comment: I rolled back the edits as it makes more sense with the accepted answer at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `submitHandler` is a callback function of the `.validate()` method (*the initialization method of the plugin*).  It's an option assigned to the whole form's behavior, ***never*** assigned to an individual field.

The `submitHandler`...

- can never be used inside of [the `.rules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).  Only the individual rules and the `messages` option can be inside of the `.rules()` method.
- can never be used inside of [the `rules` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules) of the `.validate()` method.
- can only be used inside of the [`.validate()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) or [`.setDefaults()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/) methods.

Proper usage...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize plugin
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // fires on a VALID form just after the submit button click event. 
            alert("alert"); 
        }
    });

});
```

OR

```
$.validator.setDefaults({  // change default options
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        // fires on a VALID form just after the submit button click event. 
        alert("alert"); 
    }
});
```

Since `.setDefaults()` needs to be called before `.validate()`, you could pull it out of the DOM ready event handler to force this to happen.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/yvj202aL/**

Comment: i have a dynamic form, so i cant use the validate function. how do i use the submitHandler or rather what is the other alternative I have.

Comment: @user2322507, even with a dynamic form, **the `.validate()` method is NOT optional - it's how the plugin must be *initialized***.  If you're not calling `.validate()` yourself, maybe it's being called automatically by your framework.  So if you cannot use `.validate()` for your plugin options, then you could use `.setDefaults()`, as mentioned in my third bullet point.

Comment: i tried adding the validate code u showed below my original code. no alert message is getting called.

Comment: @user2322507, you **cannot** call the `.validate()` method twice.  If your framework is already calling `.validate()` automatically, you cannot call it again.  See my updated answer.  `.setDefaults()` is your only option at this point.

Comment: even with setDefaults, i cant get to the alert message.

Comment: @user2322507, it works for me.  The form must be validated and contain no errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61790/discussion-between-user2322507-and-sparky).

Comment: edited my question to include what i tried and I just cant get to the `alert` message.

Comment: Your button cannot be a `type="button"` as that will trigger nothing.  You need a `type="submit"` in order for the button to trigger validation.

Comment: tried with "submit" now, still not getting the alert message.

Comment: @user2322507, Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/79wsf02e/ ~ In your case, leave out the `.validate()` because your framework is already calling it.

Comment: i will show u my sample code where I am trying in the chat. i have done exactly like u and not able to trigger the alert message.